# How to remove a column by name of a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

remove a column from the datatable identifying it by name

```
   DataTable dt;
   dt.Columns.Remove("columnName");
   dt.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

it does not work

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt= classOne.Getdatatable();
  dt.TableName = "TablaDatos";//columns:  "Name" y "Code"
```

I hope to remove the "Code" column

Comment: DataTable dt;
                 dt.Columns.Remove("Code");
                 dt.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);

it does not work

Comment: Not all columns can be removed. See the docs in the [CanRemove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumncollection.canremove?view=netframework-4.8) property

Comment: Don't create a new `DataTable` and immediately throw it away; initialize `dt` to the value you want: `DataTable dt = classOne.Getdatatable();`. You don't show any attempt to remove a column...